# Want to detect Android x86 in Ubuntu GRUB menu

Tags: bootloader

I was using Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 in my Lenovo G560 laptop.
Later I installed android x86 4.4.2 (KitKat) but the problem is GRUB is not detecting android x86 in GRUB menu.

I had also done the `sudo grub-update` in the terminal of Ubuntu, and still only Ubuntu and windows are only listed.

Moreover I also tried boot-repair, same result came.If there is some advance settings in boot-repair than I don't know.

Comment: Does `grub-update`/`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`/`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` mention anything about android? Also, how did you install android, and could you add a screenshot of GParted of how the hard disk is partitioned?

Comment: "ubuntu is not detecting android x86 in grub menu" Hmmm? Should that not be "grub is not detecting android x86 in grub menu"?

Comment: I suggest you run it in a virtual box, but I won't add this as an answer becase it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Open *40_custom* : `sudo gedit /etc/burg.d/40_custom`
- Add Android x86 menu entry : `menuentry "Android-4.3-x86" --class android {
  set root='(hd*,msdos*)'
  linux /path/android-4.3-x86/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=tx2500 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/path/android-4.3-x86 vga=788
  initrd /path/android-4.3-x86/initrd.img` ('path' and '*' as yours)
- Update grub : `sudo update-grub`
- Restart

Comment: Why androidboot.hardware=tx2500? It's not an HP Pavilion tx2500, but a Lenovo G560. I believe putting instead: androidboot.hardware=android_x86, or generic_x86 is safer to allow a boot.